# Posting Hybrid JSON Data Using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm attempting to POST using PHP cURL, but the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS data is not pure JSON format and I'm not sure json_encode will work.

POST URL: https://data.rcc-acis.org/StnData

```
POST Data: params={"elems":[{"interval":[1,0,0],"duration":"std","reduce":
{"reduce":"sum","add":"mcnt"},"season_start":"01-
01","name":"pcpn"}],"sid":"CVGthr+9","sDate":"1871-06-19","eDate":"2019-06-
19","meta":[]}
output=json
```

What's the easiest way to get the server response in JSON format? Thank you!

Comment: never heard of that hybrid json before, but anyways, where is the origin of data, might it be simpler to just process the data in php as an array and use `json_encode` instead?

Comment: unless you want to go clunky and use regular expressions or string functions with that string above, but i'd suggest use a proper array, encode, then send a post request using curl

Comment: @Ghost: http://xmacis.rcc-acis.org/ Click "Single-Station" -> "Graphs" -> "Accumulation Graphs"